# Screen does 2560x1440 resolution with some old style port but cannot do it through HDMI

Tags: resolution

I have an old dell 3008wfpt monitor connected with an old stationary computer through DVI-D that I have been using a 2560x1600 resolution on for years but now got a new laptop that I wanted to connect to the screen using a HDMI connection but am not able to use a resolution higher than 1920x1200. The laptop is a MSI GS65 Stealth 9SG. RTX 2080 graphics card.

What to do?

Thanks

Comment: I recommend checking all of your drivers to make sure they are up-to-date, especially your graphics drivers.

Comment: The HDMI port on either the monitor or the computer (likely the monitor) does not have enough bandwidth to push 2560x1600. You must either use DisplayPort or DVI-D to run it at native resolution.